# How to zero pad the build counter in TeamCity

Tags: teamcity, teamcity-8.0

I'm trying to follow some guidance from [this article](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/magazine/jj851071.aspx) which describes NuGet and SemVer best practices.

Point #3 states that I should "Use leading zeros in the numerical suffix to auto-increment prereleases" but I am struggling working out how I can zero pad the `build.counter` parameter in TeamCity so that I get `0025` instead of `25`.

Does anyone have a mechanism to handle this?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You could write a powershell script like:

```
function Update-BuildNumber([string]$buildNumber)
{
    $VersionComponents = $buildNumber.Split(".")
    $buildNumber = ""
    foreach($VersionComponent in $VersionComponents)
    {
        $index = [array]::IndexOf($VersionComponents, $VersionComponent)
        if (($index + 1) -eq $VersionComponents.Count)
        {
            $buildNumber += "00" + $VersionComponent
        }
        else
        {
            $buildNumber += $VersionComponent + "."
        }
    }
    Write-Output "##teamcity[buildNumber '$buildNumber']"
}
```

And call it from a Teamcity build step and pass the parameter `%build.number%` something like:

```
Update-BuildNumber -buildNumber %build.number%
```

Comment: If your build number is a simple counter (1, 2, 3, 4, ...), you could accomplish this using a PowerShell one liner in TeamCity: `"##teamcity[buildNumber '{0}']" -f ([Int32]%build.number%).ToString("0000") | Write-Host`

Comment: Where would you put this one line in the build process to work?

Comment: Six years later and I used this answer to do exactly this :D I've now changed the correct answer to this one.

Answer (score 3):

If I were you, I would make use of [GitVersion](https://github.com/Particular/GitVersion).  It includes an option to use a `LegacySemVerPadded` version of the generated version number.  There are various other [alternatives of the generated version number](https://github.com/Particular/GitVersion/wiki/Variables) as well.

There is a TeamCity Meta Runner for it [here](https://github.com/JetBrains/meta-runner-power-pack/tree/master/gitversion).

GitVersion does the work of calculating the new Semantic Version Number for you, based on the current state of your repository.

Failing that, yeah, do the work elsewhere, in PowerShell, and then use [TeamCity Service Messages](http://confluence.jetbrains.com/display/TCD7/Build+Script+Interaction+with+TeamCity) to change the build number in TeamCity.  You can find a PowerShell Module [here](https://github.com/psake/psake-contrib/blob/master/teamcity.psm1).

That provides some helper functions for doing just that.

Comment: Thanks - I'll have a look at GitVersion.

Comment: @starskythehutch it is what we are using in-house, and what I will be making of use of in this Project, https://github.com/chocolatey/ChocolateyGUI, so feel free to ask any questions :-)